# How to add a CardView with Description Animation

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I have an mockup for my android app look at this 
URL: https://xd.adobe.com/view/d7566c3b-940f-491b-938d-e7151b136cd4/screen/347dfc3b-7ec7-4e5a-84e0-c997f1df418f/Mainscreen

in this example you can click on "Miete" and the next screen will pop up from cardview a description field.

my question how can I add this description

Comment: On a side note: It must read *-INSGESAMT-* (only one "m") and *-LETZTE AKTIVITÄTEN-*.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use wrap content as height of cardview and use textview inside it below title so on click make the textview visible or invisible.